# Flutter: Using Shared Preferences to Save Locale Choice

Tags: dart, flutter

I built an app to use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences#-example-tab-) package to store a user's chosen locale that will override whatever is the current locale by following [this](https://gist.github.com/ilikerobots/474b414138f3f99150dbb3d0cc4cc721) example.

The example worked as it should but currently I am trying to find a way to combine the shared preferences package with the tutorial so that users could save their language of choice.

This is the current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localization_intl/locale/locales.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
}

Future<bool> saveLocalePreference(SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate delegate) async{
  SharedPreferences preferences =  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  preferences.setString("delegate", delegate.toString());

  return preferences.commit();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  bool isSaved = false;
  SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate _localeOverrideDelegate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _localeOverrideDelegate = new SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate(null);
    super.initState();
  }

  onLocaleChange(Locale locale) {
    setState(() {
      _localeOverrideDelegate = new SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate(locale);
      saveLanguage(_localeOverrideDelegate);
    });
  }

  void makeDialog(){
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
            content: new Text("Locale has been Saved!")
        )
    );
  }

  void saveLanguage(SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate delegate){
    saveLocalePreference(delegate).then((bool commited){
      isSaved = commited;
      setState(() {
        commited = true;
        print(commited);
      });
      makeDialog();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        _localeOverrideDelegate,
        AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', ""),
        Locale('es', ""),
        Locale('fr', "")
      ],
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(onLocaleChange: onLocaleChange),
    );
  }
}

typedef void LocaleChangeCallback(Locale locale);

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  final LocaleChangeCallback onLocaleChange;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.onLocaleChange}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

    print(myLocale);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).title
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).buttonText),
                onPressed: (){}),
            new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text("ENGLISH"),
                onPressed: (){
                  widget.onLocaleChange(const Locale("en", ""));
                }),
            new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text("SPANISH"),
                onPressed: (){
                  widget.onLocaleChange(const Locale("es", ""));
                }),
            new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text("FRENCH"),
                onPressed: (){
                  widget.onLocaleChange(const Locale("fr", ""));
                }),
            new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text("DEFAULT"),
                onPressed: (){
                  widget.onLocaleChange(null);
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is:

The shared preferences does not seem to work as it will still go back to the default language whenever the app restarts. I tried removing the `initState()` but it will return this error -

```
I/flutter ( 5254): The getter 'type' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 5254): Receiver: null
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Where do you try to retrieve the previously saved setting? I don't see a `getString()` anywhere.

Comment: Do i need to make a getString() method in the initState() ? Wouldnt that just return a null value since I havent saved anything yet the first time?

Comment: Yes, and you have to deal with that by picking a default (and probably immediately saving it). With shared preferences you always have to write code to deal with initial installation where there are none, and set them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ?

```
if(delegate!=null){
preferences.setString("delegate", delegate.toString());
}
```